# Delete files in Linux unrecoverable

Tags: deleted-files

What's the ideal command or software to erase files in Linux so they are unrecoverable?

A kernel command or any other command or software that would delete the files and make them unrecoverable

Answer (score 3):

There is a `shred` utility that asks filesystem to write file on the same blocks. There is also `srm` that modifies file many times and creates mess on its place.

Beware of the following things:

- SSD: Controller will use different pages for rewrites. It may be better to remove and then force TRIM: use `fstrim` (may not work if AHCI is not enabled)
- Hardware RAID: you really do not know how raid controller will place your data.
- Journaled filesystems like Ext3. It may depend on filesystem options: https://serverfault.com/questions/70521/securely-deleting-files-on-linux-journaled-filesystem

Answer (score -3):

press Ctrl+Alt+T to get a new GUI terminal window, then write:

```
shred -uvz -n3 c:/file.txt or c:/ for the whole folder shredded
```

Comment: I'm confused by your reference to c:/file.txt or c:/ -- we're on a Unix & Linux site.